# Symmetries higher dimensional cube fixing subcubes

Tags: isometries, hypercube

Which is the group of rotational isometries of an $n$ dimensional hypercube  fixing an $m$ dimensional element (an $m$ dimensional subcube)? I know for example that it is $A_n$ for $m=0$ (symmetries fixing a vertex).

Comment: What does "fixing" mean? Pointwise or as a set?

Comment: I'm curious. Where do your hypercube problems come from?

Comment: As a set. The problems come from a project i'm working on, but i'm quite confused.

Comment: Have you tried realizing the group of symmetries as the group of signed permutation matrices with determinant 1?   In that language these subgroups should be easy to describe in terms of a block decomposition.

Comment: In these terms, i guess fixing an $m$ subcube means asking that the isometry permutes the $n−m$ faces of the hypercube whose intersection is that subcube. In terms of permutation matrix, it means that there should be two blocks: one of dimension $n−m$, whose entries must be $1$, and one of dimension $m$. That means that the requested group is a subgroup of index $2$ (for the determinant $=1$ condition) of $S_{n-m} \times (\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr S_m)$. Am i missing something? And, what exactly that group is?

Comment: The permutation of the $n-m$ faces that cut out that hypercube must in fact be an even permutation, so your subgroup is $A_{n-m}$ times the determinant 1 part of $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr S_m)$. Seeing the first part I think is easier if you rephrase things in terms of the dual cross polytope.

Comment: Why do you say the permutation of the $n-m$ faces must be even? It is not true for example for $n=3$ and $m=1$ (rotational isometries of the ordinary cube fixing an edge). The faces may interchange (by a rotation of $\pi$ angle around the axis through the fixed edge and the opposite one), and the group you obtain is indeed $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the group generated by this rotation).